Unanble to update from 22.04 to 24.04 due to possible network or repository problem
Updating from UK server and having trying with both Wi-Fi and ethernet connection I get the message below. The 22.04 is fully up to date.
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu kinetic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F, E:The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu kinetic InRelease' is not signed.

Firstly, you need to disable all external repositories (e.g. wine repo) and remove packages installed from those repositories to perform the upgrade. More importantly, the upgrade path is buggy, and many people are experiencing severe problems. Either fresh install 24.04 or don't install for now

Thank you. Will forget up-date for a few months

Upstream Wine, among many other non-Ubuntu sources, has been breaking Ubuntu LTS release-upgrades for over 15 years.
It's well-known in the support community, as is the solution.

Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible.

Uninstall ALL upstream Wine (and all other non-Ubuntu) packages.
Disable the upstream Wine (and all other non-Ubuntu) apt sources.


Perform the release-upgrade.

After the release upgrade has been successful,

Review each non-Ubuntu application to see if you still need the non-Ubuntu version. Maybe the Ubuntu version of Wine will work instead.
Reinstall the non-Ubuntu software that you still need.



It's your role as the system administrator to learn the skills required to perform those three steps. Folks who are unwilling or unable to learn those skills should avoid installing non-Ubuntu software.
There are two software distribution methods baked into Ubuntu that make all this admin work and breakage unnecessary. One is over 25 years old, the other is 10 years old. Both are free. Both are open source. Tell your favorite upstream software developers to start using them.

How does one know if apps are Ubuntu or not when downloaded from as Ubuntu software. ie LibreOffice etc. Also how are they disabled?

When you download from Ubuntu software, they are snap apps, and should not cause any issue.
